# Minimizing number of db-queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say we have a `Post` model.

In the beginning of a view I need to display the total number of posts, typically by

```
@posts.size
```

Later in the view I need to display all posts, typically by

```
@posts.each do |post|  

end
```

This results in two queries.

If I had done the queries in the opposite order, it had resulted in one single query (presumably utilizing CACHE).

Is there any "trick" where I can achieve the (first) mentioned order with only one db query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example [#fragment-caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching)

```
<% cache 'posts_size' do %>
  <%= @posts.size %>
<% end %>
```

Then when a `Post` is created you can expire the fragment

```
expire_fragment 'posts_size'
```